# Styled text in JasperReports does not show when exported to Excel

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

There is a jasper report that changes the font color of a text field depending on the value.
The textfield expression is 
    `"<style isBold='false'>" + $V{dayMeasure} + "</style>" + "\n" + "\n" +  (($V{valid_date} != null) ? "<style forecolor='red' isBold='true'>" + new DecimalFormat("£ ###,##0.00").format($V{total}) + "</style>" : "")`.

This is shown in red when exported as a PDF.
But the same does not work in Excel.

Is there a setting that needs to be changed for styled markup to work with Excel.

Comment: The Excel exporter documentation is on page 275 (page 263 within the document) of this pdf: http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-library-ultimate-guide

Comment: Which Excel exporter are you using? JRXlsExporter, JRXlsxExporter, or JExcelApiExporter?

Comment: @GenericJon - I could not find the details about the exporter being used in any of the files. Can you tell me which file should I look at to find out about it ?

Comment: @Lisa : The information in the document does not answer my question.  understand that XLS falls under Grid Exporter and they do not render overlapped cells in Excel etc... but my question is not related to it.